# Google Analytics screen tracking swift 3.0 not working

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, swift3

Google's code for screen tracking isn't working in swift 3.0
This is the code:

```
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: name)

    let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
    tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

I am getting the following error: "cannot convert value of type NSMutableDictionary? to type [NSObject: AnyObject] in coercion".
Any help please?

Comment: What happens if you remove `as [NSObject : AnyObject]`? The compiler should hint the right type (also do ALT+CLICK on `.send` to see what it returns).

Comment: Yeah it returns void and it expects an argument of [AnyHashable: Any]. I tried to cast the NSMutableDictionary to [AnyHashable: Any] and still not working: "cast always fail"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast to NSDictionary first. This works:

```
tracker.send(builder.build() as NSDictionary as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.